# Packaging Succeeded but Publishing Failed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, publishing

I am trying to publish a very large raster data set, ~330GB. I get the general error: "Packaging succeeded but publishing failed"

The geoprocessing results say to check the server logs.

The server logs provide general error messages:

- Failed to construct instance of service
  'TestBrandon/ImgTest_321.MapServer'. Service startup timeout.
- Core server call to create service failed (/admin/createService).
- Failed to create the service.: ERROR: Service failed to start,
  Internal server error.
- Error executing tool. PublishServiceDefinition Job ID:
  j360531ad8cd940a490f8f7ee2085dc49 : ERROR 001369: Failed to create
  the service. Failed to execute (Publish Service Definition).
- The service 'TestBrandon/ImgTest_321.MapServer' was not found.
  Verify the service exists and is started.

There is nothing wrong with my configuration settings; I am able to publish if I only do half of the tiles. It is also not corrupt data because I successfully published both halves of the data set.

It also has nothing to do with the cache, because I have it set to manually build cache afterwards (and I can publish with building cache when I only publish half of the tiles).

I do have a lot of .SOC processes running on the server machine, but I tried stopping all of them during after-hours with no luck.

It seems like it is stemming from the first error message:
"Service startup timeout"

I'm guessing it is just taking too long with the large data set. Is there anyway I can increase this time so it does not timeout?

Running ArcMap 10.4.1

Comment: This is possibly something that should go direct to Esri or local support

Comment: I have been in contact with Esri, they have no idea.

Comment: You can try increasing the time outs on the publishing service.    I hope in this case you have a datastore reference set and you're not really moving 300gb of files from your client to the server. Thats just my personal opinion, you can do it if you want.....

Comment: Yes, I have the data registered and am not moving the data to the server. I have also tried increasing these publishing properties:              "The maximum time a client can use a service" and "The maximum time a client will wait to get a service" to essentially unlimited time.

Comment: Sometimes this can mean a net-bot is killing long-running network connections.

Comment: @Vince Can you elaborate or point to a source for this?

Comment: Not really. I had a customer for whom the install went great, and the next day it didn't work.  Three months later they were finally able to determine that some security app installed by corporate IT was sniffing traffic and killing long-duration connections.

Comment: I'd second @Midavalo comment and try tech support. You've covered the basics.They'll be able to search past calls and see if theres something similar and let you know what was done to solve that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I had to change the permission level on the "python27" folder on the C:\ drive of our publishing machine. The ArcGIS Server user account did not have full permissions. Giving it full permissions allowed it to successfully publish.